# How to resolve duplicate post backs due to multiple jquery files?

Tags: javascript, duplicates, postback, conflict

Below are the JS files sequence on my master page :-

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.reject.css" rel="stylesheet" />         
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.reject.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>  
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/js/jquery.dcverticalmegamenu.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"></script>
```

My problem is,due to Javascript file "jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" the post back methods calling two times.But if i don't include that file the post back methods firing single time.

But if i don't include it,i am getting other javascript error :-

```
TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
```

And due to this error i can't remove this JS file from the master page.

I explored the issue and get some comments about it.And the reason behind it(firing event or post back two times) is two Jquery files on the page.One is "Jquery-1.7.2.min.js" and second is "jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js".

Can any one help me out on this ? How can we use both of the JS files or can remove its conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your client code is subscribing to the event twice, so you need to add code or change your code to only subscribe once.

This may help http://api.jquery.com/one/